# Proving $x^4+x^3y-x^2y+y^2>0$ with some given constraints

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have to prove the inequality $$x^4+x^3y-x^2y+y^2>0$$ holds for all pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x^2+y^2\leq1$ and $x^2>y^2$.

I would like to find a lower bound just to start, but I can't see it. Any ideas?

Comment: The inequality is NOT strict inside the disc. The LHS is 0 at $(0,0)$

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the other constraint thinking it wasn't necessary. Clearly, we can leave as $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(y) = y^2+(x^3-x^2)y+x^4$ viewed as a quadratic in variable $y$. Taking delta $\triangle = (x^3-x^2)^2 - 4x^4 = x^4((x-1)^2-4) = x^4(x-3)(x+1) < 0$ since $x^2+y^2 \le 1 \implies x^2 \le 1 \implies -1 \le x \le 1 \implies -1 \le x < 3 \implies \triangle < 0 \implies f(y) > 0$.
**Note:** This can also be shown by completing square as this method and the one above are equivalent.

Comment: $\Delta=0$ for $x=0$.

Comment: Again, my bad, not Wang ;)